# I want to create blog module in joomla that shows images as well in the module

Tags: joomla3.0

I have created Articles Category module, and choose a category to create a blog section. The modules are visible as per my need(4 columns on a page with the intro text but what I need is, with those intro text, images should also appear in those blocks). I want in each column, the article should appear with intro text and images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do changes in the file located at :
**Modules/mod_article_category/tmpl/default.php**
There in else condition i.e Not Grouped one add these lines in foreach loop in between your **li** tags  :

```
$article_images = $item->images; // Get image parameters of the article

$pictures = json_decode($article_images); // Split the parameters apart

echo "img src='" . $pictures->{'image_intro'} . "' alt='" . $pictures->{'image_intro_alt'} . "'>"; // get the intro image
```